# Convert rows using pivot and adding a grand total

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

What is the easiest way to get a sum of the data in the quantity column as the last column after the pivot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the total of values with a row then add those values together. If you have `NULL` values then use `COALESCE(column_name, 0)` to get `0` instead of `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT q.*,
       COALESCE("1", 0)
       + COALESCE("2", 0)
       + COALESCE("3", 0)
       -- ...
       + COALESCE("18", 0)
       + COALESCE("19", 0) AS gt
FROM   ( <your_previous_query> ) q
```

Or, if you are using `PIVOT` then:

```sql
SELECT p.*,                           -- use the pivot alias to get all columns
       COALESCE("1", 0)
       + COALESCE("2", 0)
       + COALESCE("3", 0)
       -- ...
       + COALESCE("18", 0)
       + COALESCE("19", 0) AS gt
FROM   your_unspecified_table_name
       PIVOT(
         <your_unspecified_pivot_clause>
       ) p                           -- include an alias for the pivot
```